# Connecting two sites

Tags: .htaccess, cookies, passwords, modx

I have developed a website (A) that needs to connect with another website (B) i.e only members of B can see site A

I can limit the incoming traffic on site A with a .htaccess rule to only come from site B, but anyone would still be able to manually type in the URLs or send a link via email:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !sitea\.co.uk [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !siteb\.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule .? - [F]
```

Is there something I could do with cookies? this does not have to be very secure, just stop casual users viewing site A without first logging into site B.

Comment: ok, just a simple iframe did the job!

Comment: But this is still possible: "but anyone would still be able to manually type in the URLs or send a link via email"

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest approach here is to have both sites managed by the same MODx install, but use a different context for each site/domain. You can then develop a simple snippet or plugin to allow access to Site A only if the user is logged in on Site B.

Try modifying the following Domain Gateway plugin to do this:
http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Using+One+Gateway+Plugin+to+Manage+Multiple+Domains

This is simple to accomplish and even though not necessary here it is also very secure ;)